# Internal temporal variable in mathematic calculation in C++

Tags: c++, casting, integer-overflow

The following example is used to illustrate my question:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{

  signed char p;
  signed char temp=100;
  signed char t=4;
  p = (temp+temp+temp+temp)/t;
  std::cout << "Hello, " << int(p)<< "!\n";
}
```

In the above codes, variable `p` is defined as the average of four `singed char` variables. However, the sum of the signed char variable (temp+temp+temp+temp) will be larger than the range of signed char. So my question is how C++ handle this situation.

Comment: If you have a mix of signed and unsigned variables, you may want to do explicit casting to make sure everything comes out the way you want. Your example does not have that problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> However, the sum of the signed char variable (temp+temp+temp+temp) will be larger than the range of signed char.

That does not matter as `char` will be promoted to `int` due to `integral promotion`. Details can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic). So operations will be done over type `int` and you will get expected result.

Comment: A platform where `int` cannot hold 400 would be illegal, as INT_MAX must be at least 32767.

Answer (score 5):

Nothing happens, because of [integral promotion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast#Integral_promotion)

> Prvalues of small integral types (such as char) may be converted to
>   prvalues of larger integral types (such as int). In particular,
>   arithmetic operators do not accept types smaller than int as
>   arguments, and integral promotions are automatically applied after
>   lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, if applicable. This conversion always
>   preserves the value.

`(temp+temp+temp+temp)` will return an integer.

`(temp+temp+temp+temp)/t` will be inside of the char range.

so `p == temp`